# Absorbing subset

Tags: functional-analysis

For each $n ≥ 1$, let $T_n = \{x ∈ l_2(N) : ||x||_1 ≤ n \}$.

For $n ≥ 1$, is $T_n$ an absorbing subset of $l_2(N) $, but why?
I would like to show that $T_n$ has empty interior, for all $n ≥ 1. $ and that $T_n$ is closed in $l_2(N)$, for all  $n ≥ 1 $.

Answer (score 1):

Since $l_1(\mathbb{N})$ is a proper subset of $l_2(\mathbb{N})$ we can take $x \in l_2(\mathbb{N})- l_1(\mathbb{N})$, i.e. $||x||_2< \infty$ and $||x||_1= \infty$. Now suppose $T_n$ is absorbing, i.e. $\exists t >0$ such that $t^{-1}x \in T_n$.
But this means that $t^{-1}||x||_1=||t^{-1}x||_1 \leq n$ or in other words $||x||_1 \leq t \ n < \infty$. Thus $x \in l_1(\mathbb{N})$ and it's a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $N=\Bbb N$: **Hint:** If $x=???$ then $x\in\ell_2(N)$ but $||x||_1=\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I am super lost. I know  that $\ell_1(N)$ is a proper subspace of $\ell_2(N)$ So this x should not exist.

Comment: You have something backwards. Saying that $\ell_1$ is a proper subset of $\ell_2$ says exactly that there exists $x\in \ell_2$ with $x\notin\ell_1$; hence $||x||_1=\\infty$.

Comment: (Typo: Of course that comment was supposed to end with "$||x||_1=\infty$".)

Comment: Still not getting it. If I understand you right than the set is empty

Comment: Then what set is empty? Look. Say $x=(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots)$, so $x\in\ell_2$ and $||x||_1=\infty$. If we had $x\in\lambda T_1$ for some $\lambda>0$ then $x=\lambda y$ with $||y||_1<1$, hence $||x||_1<\infty$. So $x\not\in \lambda T_1$. So $T_1$ is not absorbing.